# At which point of the code is the p5 is canvas created?

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

With the help of `createCanvas()` I am creating a canvas.

Since now I was pretty sure that, at the point of calling `createCanvas()` the canvas is nailed to the DOM.

But now look at this (or at better at the last line where the canvas is called):

```
//sketch.js

const gridSize = 100;

/**
 * Setup
 * @returns {void}
 */
function setup() {
  domObjects.canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  resizeGrid();
}

/**
 * Makes the Grid
 * @returns {void}
 */
function makeGrid() {
  let cell = gridSize;

  for (let i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
    line(cell * i, 0, cell * i, height);
    line(0, cell * i, width, cell * i);
  }
}

/**
 * Mainfunction
 * @returns {void}
 */
function draw() {
  try {
    background(255);

    makeGrid();
    animateWorm();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    noLoop();
  }
}
// the canvas appers at this point WTF
```

Is this a normal/usual behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the canvas appears at this point? Isn't that what you expected to happen?

Comment: Well I don´t know what to expect. I thought it would append to the DOM when I call `createCanvas()`

Comment: And is that not what's happening? Maybe try starting with a simpler example and adding print statements to understand the exact order of things.

Comment: I did all this but it seems to be more complicated...